# TypedArray.js "Object does not support this action" ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, typedarray

In this snippet from Polyfill's "typedarray.js", I'm getting an error @ the below commented portion

```
(function() {
  var orig = Object.defineProperty;
  var dom_only = !(function(){
    try{
      return Object.defineProperty({},'x',{});
    } catch(_) {
      return false;
    }
  }());
  if (!orig || dom_only) {
    Object.defineProperty = function (o, prop, desc) {
    // In IE8 try built-in implementation for defining properties on DOM prototypes.
      if (orig)
        try {
          return orig(o, prop, desc);
        } catch (_) {} //<--here throws "Object does not support this action"
      if (o !== Object(o))
        throw TypeError('Object.defineProperty called on non-object');
      if (Object.prototype.__defineGetter__ && ('get' in desc))
        Object.prototype.__defineGetter__.call(o, prop, desc.get);
      if (Object.prototype.__defineSetter__ && ('set' in desc))
        Object.prototype.__defineSetter__.call(o, prop, desc.set);
      if ('value' in desc)
        o[prop] = desc.value;
      return o;
    };
  }
}());
```

It only throws this error when I'm in IE8. Can anyone provide some clarification as to why? I've looked at other questions similar to this but it is not making sense to me. I'm a fairly new web developer, if that might help you formulate a response.

Comment: This isn't what's causing the error, but instead of `if (o !== Object(o))` I would use `if (typeof o !== 'object')`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight Thanks, that is much more readable. I didn't write this code. I downloaded it from https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/typedarray.js

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight Using `typeof` of `"object"` forbids functions, which are objects (and therefore a valid target for `defineProperty`) but produce a `typeof` of `"function"`. There may also be other `typeof` weirdness in older IE which can be bypassed by testing `Object(o)`.